# How to align radio buttons while using an unordered list to style a form?

Tags: html, css, forms, alignment

Previously, I was using tables to align my forms properly but decided to go the semantic way and use an unordered list instead. However, now I'm having a hard time aligning radio buttons  as there is no vertical-align property in an li tag to easily align it with the label on the left.

This is the jsFiddle of my problem:

[Form Alignment Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/jAN72/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how do you want to align but you do not need   `float: left;` on `.main_form label`